# iterm2 stopped showing cyrillic in Mojave (Terminal.app works fine)

Tags: macos, iterm2

iTerm2 stopped showed cyrillic letters (it shows ? instead of them). Terminal.app worked fine. System localization was setup to Russian.
Everything were working in High Sierra

Clarification: iTerm2 is usually used not as  'ssh' client but as regular terminal app on client macOS machine instead.

Answer (score 2):

Solution is simple - just add `export LC_ALL=ru_RU.UTF-8` to ~/.bashrc

Comment: Or `~/.zshrc` if you use zsh shell

Answer (score 2):

I would like to not that changing LC_ALL to russian is not good option here since it will change entire locale variable which will change the behaviour of other applications, I don't want to have russian in terminal output on the servers for example. So I would suggest to change it to `en_US.UTF-8` instead.

Comment: Why not if regular system localization (one from System Settings) is arleady configured to Russian (and it's not server machine )

Comment: Because it might not be configured to russian at some of the user which will came for this solution, even more some of the users might not be russian at all but still wants a proper cyrillic in their terminal.